# Parallax scroll with easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element that move relative to scroll. I use jQuery for this:

```
$('#object').css('transform','translateY('+($(window).scrollTop()*.4)+'px)');
```

CSS

```
#object {
    width:200px;
    top:100%;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

This works well, but moves my element directly without any easing (delay).
By setting a transition using css I get some of the effect that I'm looking for, but doesn't look good if I scroll at the same time:

```
transition: 400ms ease;
```

Is it possible to do this smooth, but in a more elegant way?

Comment: hi. i found your question when I was trying to figure out how to make momentum(smooth? kinetic?) scrolling like on this website https://www.adamunderwear.com/ but your solution didn't work for me :( I was wondering if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. The problem was the css "ease". Ease means that it will start slow and end slow, which will result in at the time scrolling is active it will always be on the slow start. However if you use css "ease-out" it will always start fast and slow down in the end. So use this:

```
transition: 400ms ease-out;
```

Or cubic-bezier if you want to customize the easing-curve yourself:

```
transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.235, 0.615, 0.185, 0.995);
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing a parallax effect you will set a new `translateY()` on every scroll event that triggers. The event triggers really often and normally there should be no need for a transition. If you still experience bad rendering it is probably because the browser does not render on every event. You can force the browser to do so by using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

```
var translate = function() {
    $('#object').css('transform','translateY('+($(window).scrollTop()*.4)+'px)');
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(translate);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but no difference. The problem when I'm using css transition is that the animation only starts after I stop scrolling. And you say there shouldn't be no need for a transition, the whole point is that I want to do it smooth/ease. But don't have to use transistion of course.

Comment: animations starts after you stop scrolling? I don't understand what you are aiming for. parallax is different scroll speed for different layers.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. But I'm not sure that you understand what I want to accomplish. With the provided code (without transition) everything works fine - but it's without easing. An example of what I want to accomplish: http://www.apple.com/tv/. After scrolling you can se the white boxes move the scrolled direction. It's like a delay, that's what I'm looking for.